# Android permission protection level "normal" are never re-granted

Tags: android, android-permissions

While testing the Android API 28 I came across a bug, whenever the application that defined a custom-permission with protection level normal gets uninstalled, all the other applications that do not define this permissions but request it in the manifest are never re-granted this permission even after system reboot (and surprisingly even if that application re-defines such a permission!). The dangerous permissions can be re-granted via user-prompt and the signature permissions are auto-re-granted as usual. Is this behavior something that is expected or is it unusual?

```
EVENT: Applications installed (in-order) : App1, App2, App3

App1's Manifest: <permission android:name="X"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<permission android:name="Y/>
<permission android:name="Z"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>

<uses-permission android:name="X"/>
<uses-permission android:name="Y"/>
<uses-permission android:name="Z"/>

App1's request: requestPermissions(new String[] "Z"},1);

App1's permissions granted : X,Y & Z are granted (Z after user-prompt)

////////////////////////////////////////////////

App2's Manifest: <permission android:name="X"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<permission android:name="Y/>
<permission android:name="Z"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>

<uses-permission android:name="X"/>
<uses-permission android:name="Y"/>
<uses-permission android:name="Z"/>

App2's request: requestPermissions(new String[]{"Z"},1);

App2's permissions granted: X, Y & Z (Z after user-prompt)
////////////////////////////////////////////////
App3's manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="X"/>
<uses-permission android:name="Y"/>
<uses-permission android:name="Z"/>

App3's request: requestPermissions(new String[]{"Z"},1);

App3's permissions granted: X, Y & Z (Z after user-prompt)
////////////////////////////////////////////////
EVENT: Uninstalled App1
////////////////////////////////////////////////
App2 Permissions Granted: X & Z (Z after user-prompt; permission Y not 
granted even if this application re-defines it, and the permission Y exists 
on device - checked via "pm list permissions")
////////////////////////////////////////////////
App3 Permissions Granted: X & Z (Z after user-prompt; permission Y not 
granted even if the permission Y exists on device - checked via 
"pm list permissions")
////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

So is this expected behavior from Android OS?

Comment: I am not surprised by this. Starting with Android 5.0 (IIRC), Android prohibits App2 from being installed if it defines the same permission as one that already exists (`Y`)... unless App2 is signed by the same signing key that signed the one defining the existing permission (App1). If both apps are signed by the same signing key, App2's permission definition is ignored, at least in part. So, I can see where symptoms like yours coulld come up. Custom permissions are mostly for device manufacturers and other pre-installed apps, where apps do not get removed.

Comment: Ahh I understand it now (I thought custom-permissions are meant to be commonly used by developers!), however this issue should not arise at all and it would be considered a bug, yes?

Comment: It is definitely an undocumented behavior, as very little about custom permissions is documented. Whether it is a bug depends a lot on what Google's intentions were here.